# SSS - How to get a nice falloff between glowing translucent areas and dark spots?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, subsurface-scattering

I'm new to Blender and I'm trying to recreate this effect with Cycles. The  render below was made with Modo.

I've tried using Cycles SSS but results are very different. Can't seem to get that nice falloff between the glowing translucent areas and dark spots.

[image: modo sss]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried and how it's different?

Comment: Here's a preview. I'm not even using SSS on this one, but that's the closest I've got. Notice the model isn't the same tho, but you get the idea. http://i.imgur.com/PcJcf1U.jpg

Comment: How did you generate this shape?

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn It's a procedural displacement generated in Modo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I was finally able to replicate it!! I imported the same model to Blender to really compare. All I needed was to pump  up the transulcent BSDF amount and I just did it with an 'Add Shader' node. It looks great now and renders so fast with GPU enabled. I'm so impressed with Blender and I think I'll stick with this software for now. :-)

[image]

Comment: I'm a blender newbie/amateur but never in a million years would I have thought of using the Add shader with 2 Translucent shaders. What a great material it makes.